# hadoop installation issue window on executing start-df

Tags: hadoop, installation

I am trying to install hadoop on the personal laptop

OS windows 64 bit

issue:- unable to execute the start-dfs.cmd It is throwing error "the system cannot find the file hadoop"

on further debugging i found the line causing error is

start "Apache Hadoop Distribution" hadoop namenode
start "Apache Hadoop Distribution" hadoop datanode

any inputs will be helpful.
if needed i can share my desktop